# Typescript module importing cases classes to be undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have two files

app.js

```
///<reference path='mongodb.d.ts'/>
///<reference path='MyDatabase.ts'/>
module MyModule {
  import mongodb = module("mongodb");
  new mongodb.Server();
  var db = new MyDatabase(); // this will not work with first import line in Database.js, but work with second
}
```

MyDatabase.js

```
///<reference path='mongodb.d.ts'/>

import mongodb = module("mongodb"); // adding this line here, will cause that app.js will not see MyDatabase class

module MyModule {
   import mongodb = module("mongodb"); // adding this line this will cause that classes in this module cant use mongodb

   export class MyData {
      _id: mongodb.Id; // second import line will cause this to be compilation error, with first line it works
   }

   export class MyDatabase {
       public test(): void {
          //with second line i can access mongodb here
       }
   }
}
```

So question is, what am I missing? How should i go about importing mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be confusing external modules (`export` / `import`) with the "internal" `module` block? Import declarations should only be present at the top level of a file.

Comment: well as I've said, if its on top of MyDatabase.js, app.js wont see MyDatabase class

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that TS reference paths are *includes*, not *imports*. As long as you do not use import/export, the TS compiler puts everything in the 'global module', using reference paths to stitch it together.

Once you start using import/export in a file, that file will be interpreted as its own module, no longer part of the global module. Have a look into the TS language specification, section 9.1, for the details.

So, I suspect that -once you start using import in `MyDataBase.ts`- you'll need to import that file as an external module, too (instead of just referencing it).

Comment: That sounds like what is happening. But isn't there a way to not use import? Should I get all sources from mongodb, and add it to my project and let typescript to put it all in one file?

Comment: As long as all your external modules can be imported, why not do the same for your own modules (ie, import MyDataBase in app)?